# How can I get a long running PreBuildEvent to output data while its running, instead of after?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, npm, bower, gulp

I have a visual studio MVC project and I use NPM and Bower.  I restore my NPM and Bower packages as part of my build process via a pre-build command line, so the people that use the project don't need to know about npm install, etc.

Unfortunately, for whatever reason, the output is not rendered to the output window until after the package restore has finished.  When building a project for the first time, this can take a very long time and I don't want to leave my users hanging, waiting for visual studio to respond.

Is there a way I can set up my pre-build command line prompt to write to the output *as* it runs, rather than *after* it runs?

csproj call to run the command

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>
        cd "$(ProjectDir)"
        echo "generating output for the output window prior to running the long running process"
        dir            
        echo "now running long running task"
        call pre-build.bat $(ConfigurationName)
    </PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

As you can see, I have some debug output in there, a couple of calls to "echo" and a dir call.  I would expect to see those commands output to the output window prior to the long running task, but this doesnt happen.  Instead I just see the following output until *after* the package restore runs

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
```

Because I'm not seeing output from the echo's and the dir, I'm thinking there is either a different way to run this task, or VS / MsBuild just doesnt support showing the output I want until after the task is run.  Does anyone know how to set it up to write the output *as* the task runs?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Target & Message elements:

```
<Target Name="UserMessage" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="Your message here" />
</Target>
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, for a msg that says "this may take a while".  I hope I can just stream the output to the output window though.